# Can inline lambda initializer capture 'this' pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Can inline member initialization lambda capture and use `this` pointer?

```
struct A{
  int a = 42;
  int b = [this](){
    return this->a * 4;
  }();
};
```

Is it valid C++11 code (according to specification) or is it just a GCC extension?

If it is valid, why do I have to use `this->` when referring to member `a`?

Comment: This kind of questions one should post on StackOverflow! Welcome! :)

Comment: easy to check with `-pedantic` option

Comment: It working with `-pedantic` with both GCC 4.7 and clang 3.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it valid c++11 code?

No. Only lambdas in block scope can have capture lists:

> C++11 5.1.2/9 A *lambda-expression* whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope is a *local lambda expression*; any other *lambda-expression* shall not have a *capture-list* in its *lambda-introducer*.

So it seems this is a GCC extension. (As noted in the comments, this is an [open issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1632), so might well become standard one day.)

> why I have to use `this->` while referring to member a?

You don't, at least with the version of GCC I'm using: http://ideone.com/K857VC.

Comment: I suppose N3797 rephrased this a bit: `A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (3.3.3) is a local lambda expression;
any other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer.`

Comment: @MarcoA.: Thanks, I was just looking to see whether this changes in C++14. That doesn't change the answer; you still can't capture `this` (being a *simple-capture*) in a non-local lambda.

Comment: OTOH, since NSDMIs are essentially syntatic sugar for the constructor's member initializer list, it's arguable that it effectively has block scope (or something similar to it)...

Comment: This is [CWG 1632](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1632).

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks for the link. It certainly makes sense to capture `this` here, even if the current standard disallows it.